graph.triplets seems not work as expected
The graph is generated is generated from the iterative process. It looks like this ↓
graph = graph.outerJoinVertices(updatedNode2vdata)((vid, old, newOpt) => newOpt.getOrElse(old))

    //debug graph: Graph[VD, ED]

    val old_nodes = graph.vertices.collect()
    val old_triplets = graph.triplets.collect()

    val old_comms_set = old_nodes.map({ case (vid, vdata) => {
      vdata.community
    }
    }).toSet

    val test_comms_set = old_triplets.flatMap( et => {
      Seq(et.dstAttr.community, et.srcAttr.community)

    }
    ).toSet

    val test_result = old_comms_set.equals(test_comms_set)



    println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
    println(test_result)
    println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
    //debug

It is expected that test_result is always true. However, after the first iteration step, it is true. In the subsequent iteration steps, it is false.
As shown in the following figure, even the size is not correct.
enter image description here
It's so weird. Is it a bug or something？

Scala version is 2.12.10
Spark verion is 3.2.0
